# redux unit testing Store.dispatch()

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, karma-jasmine, enzyme, redux-mock-store

i have a basic react component like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import store from 'src/home/store';
class PageLoading extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: this.props.message
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        store.dispatch({ type: 'SET_NOTIFICATION_DIALOG', status: '200', message: this.state.message, model: 'LOADING' });
    }

    render(){
        return(<div />);
    }
}


export default PageLoading;
```

how to unit this component ..?

i am using karma with ezyme.
i have written this below code but this is not working

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import PageLoading from 'src/home/components/PageLoading';

const middlewares = [];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("Page Loading",()=>{
    it("testing shoul dispatch action on calling componentdid mount",()=>{
        const initialState = {}
        const store = mockStore(initialState)
        const wrapper = mount(<PageLoading message="loading"/>);
         const actions = store.getActions();
        const expectedPayload = {type: 'SET_NOTIFICATION_DIALOG', status: '200', message:"loading", model: 'LOADING' };
         expect(actions).toEqual([expectedPayload])
    })
})
```

i think it is not getting the store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should [provide the store at the top of your app heirarchy](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#passing-the-store).

Use [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) to connect to the store and inject `dispatch` in your component props:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class PageLoading extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: this.props.message
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.dispatch({ type: 'SET_NOTIFICATION_DIALOG', status: '200', message: this.state.message, model: 'LOADING' });
    }

    render(){
        return(<div />);
    }
}

export default connect()(PageLoading);
```

In your test, you can substitute the store for the connected component by passing it as a prop:

```
describe("Page Loading",()=>{
    it("testing shoul dispatch action on calling componentdid mount",()=>{
        const initialState = {}
        const store = mockStore(initialState)
        const wrapper = mount(<PageLoading store={store} message="loading"/>);
         const actions = store.getActions();
        const expectedPayload = {type: 'SET_NOTIFICATION_DIALOG', status: '200', message:"loading", model: 'LOADING' };
         expect(actions).toEqual([expectedPayload])
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot !!!! your answer saved my life :-)))) but I've another question, can I use the real store instead mock store?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
it("testing shoul dispatch action on calling componentdid mount",()=>{
        const initialState = {}
        const store = mockStore(initialState)
        const wrapper = mount(<PageLoading message="loading"/>);
         const actions = store.getActions();
        const expectedPayload = {type: 'SET_NOTIFICATION_DIALOG', status: '200', message:"loading", model: 'LOADING' };
        spyOn(store, 'dispatch');

        expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith([expectedPayload]);
    })
```

If it don`t work with spy on store, try spy on mockedstore and mockedstore.dispatch